# Missing module routing_enums_pb2 when using pyinstaller

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller, or-tools

I am trying to pack my VRP model as a single exe file, using pyinstaller.

after the pyinstaller operations, when I run the exe there reports an erro concerning missing module routing_enums_pb2:

[image]

where could be going wrong?

BTW: I have no problem to run the model in pycharm

my lastest full codes is here:
https://gist.github.com/Westlife1002/03f5f2a1b03841a81221623bce63951e

Comment: Please indicate when you are cross-posting.